# jQuery to tsx conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert this jquery to tsx and i am having some issues

```
$(".nav__trigger").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("nav--active");
});
```

my initial approach

```
const button = document.querySelector(".nav__trigger");
console.log(button);
button?.addEventListener("click", function (this: any, e: any) {
  console.log("clicked");
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector(this).parent().classList.toggle(".nav--active");
});
```

Comment: Seems like you want `this.parentElement.classList...`. `this` is a DOM element,so you cannot pass it to `document.querySelector`. https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#parent . There is also https://plainjs.com/javascript/

Comment: And if you are really using React then you shouldn't directly manipulate the DOM anyway.